# How to Translate an MLP Problem to an ARFF File

Tags: neural-network, weka, arff, mlp

I have a problem that has to be translated into an arff file but i cant figure it out and its very important. We have a robot which has to reach X without going to the black squares. It can go up, down, left, right or stay to its position. These are going to be the outputs of the multilayer perceptron. The inputs are going to be the coordinates of the squares.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case there are 2 problems:
1) can robot enter the field? - you do not need MLP for this problem if the location of the black squares is fixed the decision table will do the job
2) which field (from all valid fields near to the robot position) robot should choose - for this problem you could use MLP for multiclass classification (up, down, left, right). You can prepare arff with instances for each class with following attributes (robots position, distance counted in squares  to x using only straight lines, number of black squares crossed by straight line, up square 0/1, down square 0/1, right square 0/1,  left square 0/1) - e.g 0 for white square 1 for black square (as a result for classification problem 1)

I hope it will help.